# Binding modified key in evil mode

Tags: key-bindings, evil

I wanted to bind M-n to transpose-chars in evil insert state, and tried
`(define-key evil-insert-state-map "M-n" 'transpose-chars)`
But that didn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Try `(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "M-n") 'transpose-chars)`.

Comment: This has got to be a duplicate question. Hope someone will find the dup...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `(define-key KEYMAP KEY DEF)` the `KEY` is internal representation of keys, where prefix keys must be `\C-` or `\M-`.  A way to convert keys into internal representation is to use `(kbd KEYS)` function, where `KEYS` is string. In your question it could be two variants:

- `(define-key evil-insert-state-ma‌​p "\M-n" 'transpose-chars)`
- `(define-key evil-insert-state-ma‌​p (kbd "M-n") 'transpose-chars)`

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Sequences.html